# Does Knime support Arm architecture?

Tags: etl, knime

I can only download the Knime installation package for Windows, Mac, and Linux on Knime's official website. There is no Knime installation package that supports the Arm architecture for download. Is it because Knime does not support Arm architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge.  It would probably be best to ask this question again on the KNIME forum on the development channel at https://forum.knime.com/c/knime-development/21 - that way someone from KNIME will likely be able to provide a full answer as to whether you might be able to build from source, for example